# Javascript: Parse vs. Execute

Tags: javascript

Just trying to sort out terminology here: What is the difference between "parsing" and "executing" javascript, if any? I assume that parsing is kind of "taking the JS code into account", while executing is what happens after aka "running the code".

Comment: the browser have to parse the js code in order to execute it: a parser returns a stuff that the machine can execute from a sequence of symbols.
Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern, this is the design pattern beyond the interpreted languages.
Is kinda like *parse* means *do understand* while *execute* means *do what you understood*

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's right, parsing basically means "reading the code" and executing basically means "running the code". There's a good overview of what parsing means here: [The Journey of JavaScript: from Downloading Scripts to Execution - Part I](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/journey-of-javascript-downloading-scripts-to-execution-part-i). Worth noting that browsers can do both at the same time, so it might be parsing one part of the code while it is still executing earlier code.